# Is there an Azure API that will give me VM characteristics from RateCard description

Tags: api, azure, attributes, virtual-machine

Is there an Azure API that spits out details/attributes/characteristics of a specific meter provided through the [RateCard API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004)?

An example meter object from the API looks like this.

```
    {
        "EffectiveDate": "2016-09-01T00:00:00Z",
        "IncludedQuantity": 0.0,
        "MeterCategory": "Virtual Machines",
        "MeterId": "40f2bbb5-1ca8-4ac5-afd6-b1e47f16314b",
        "MeterName": "Compute Hours",
        "MeterRates": {
            "0": 0.010
        },
        "MeterRegion": "US East 2",
        "MeterSubCategory": "Standard_D2_v2 VM (Windows)",
        "MeterTags": [],
        "Unit": "Hours"
    }
```

I want to know more information about the `MeterSubCategory` in this case the VM meter of `Standard_D2_v2 VM (Windows)`.  How many cores, how much memory, max number of disks, and hopefully VM throttling limits for IOPS and MB/sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know more information about the MeterSubCategory in this
>   case the VM meter of Standard_D2_v2 VM (Windows). How many cores, how
>   much memory, max number of disks

You could use Azure Virtual Machine Rest API. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-list-sizes-region).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/vmSizes?api-version={apiVersion}
```

For example:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/************/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/eastus/vmSizes?api-version=2017-12-01
```

The APi will get VM name, numberOfCores,osDiskSizeInMB,resourceDiskSizeInMB,memoryInMB,maxDataDiskCount.

> and hopefully VM throttling limits for IOPS and MB/sec.

Based on my knowledge, no API could list this, you could check Azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general).